# How to use same properties for separate API requests

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, asp.net-core-webapi

I have following two API methods:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<TransactionReadDto> TransactionGroup(TransactionGroup transactionGroup)
{
    // some code goes here
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<TransactionReadDto> TransactionHistory(TransactionHistory transactionHistory)
{
    // some code goes here
}
```

And the above code `TransactionGroup` and `TransactionHistory` classes as follows:

```
public class TransactionGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public string Cost { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionHistory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

You can see these two classes have same properties for `Name` and `Publisher` (it has more same properties than these two, this only for an example). My problem: is there any best way to handle this without using same properties in API request classes? Can I use inheritance?

If yes what is the way to do this? I mean can I put same properties into some parent class and inherit let `TransactionGroup` and `TransactionHistory` classes inherit from that base class? Is this a good approach?

Comment: yes it is a good approach, if both of these properties mean the same thing

Comment: I would just merge both classes in one or leave as it is. Nobody crreates a new class because of 2  string properties difference.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, don't do it.

You would think that you actually remove redundant code by implementing inheritance or composition here.
But the cost of reducing the amount of code is that you permanently couple the two API requests. There can be a future in which you want to change one of the API methods but not the other. This will be much harder if you have coupled these two (or even more of them).

Also, you do not really gain any readability by sharing the code. Instead, it would be even harder to read, because not all properties of `TransactionHistory` will be found in its class.

If you find that there is really far too much code duplication, you would prefer composition like this:

```
public class TransactionHistory
{
  public CommonTransactionData common { get; set; }
  public string StartDate { get; set; }
  public string EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

In this special case, you could also consider it to be clean using inheritance, but generally we follow the [composition over inheritance principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

edit: missed a property name

Comment: @derpirscher If the hierarchy of classes is clear and intended, inheritance would be okay here. This is what i have written in the last paragraph of my response.
But here we speak about two classes that represent API parameters. IF both serve the same purpose and fulfill the Liskov substitution principle, inheritance is okay.
But it seems that the question aimed only towards reusing code.

Comment: I don't think an answer like *"Generally don't do it"* is appropriate here. Yes, the composition over inheritance principle is valid in many cases. But that doesn't mean, you shouldn't use inheritance at all. In situations, where there is a clear hierarchy of classes (for instance something like `vehicle -> car` ) that share common properties and functionality, inheritance is still the way to go ...

Comment: I don't say, inheritance is appropriate here, because I don't see a any hierachy that justifies it. But starting your answer with "Generally don't do it"  for me leaves the impression, you are implying not to use inheritance at all.

Comment: @derpirscher Maybe that is a language barrier for me. What I actually mean is that if I ask myself "Should i use inheritance to reuse code?", the answer will almost always be "No".
And the question was "You can see these two classes have same properties [...]. My problem: is there any best way to handle this without using same properties in API request classes? Can I use inheritance?"

Answer (score 0):

What relation to `TransactionGroup` and `TransactionHistory` have? Is the one a subtype of the other (like for instance `Vehicle -> Car`) or do they just have equally named properties. A `Country` and a `Person` both have a `Name`, but that doesn't mean you should let a `Person` inherit from a `Country` or vice versa.

Especially, if I look at your classes, they both have exclusive properties (ie `Cost` only exists in the `TransactionGroup` and the `StartDate` only in `TransactionHistory`). But if you let one inherit from the other, it means the other will have all properties as well. Does it make sense for a `Group` to have a `StartDate` or does it make sense for a `History` to have a `Cost`? If not, inheritance is not the proper way.